# Evaluating one thread performance across all the methods

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, benchmarking, timing

There is one thread which executes say 50 methods across several packages. I want to evaluate execution time for each method. This thread wakes on a signal and process this 50 method.

Answer or discussion is encouraged but please read my notes:

1. Please do not suggest to put System.nano/mills at the start and at the end of each method.
2. No profiler suggestion please.
3. Do not suggest to mess this application with performances evaluation lines.
4. Appreciate if someone gives an example using BTrace or ThreadMXBean or anything new.

Like to evaluate programmatically, so appreciate if anyone has better ideas.

Comment: The BTrace distribution has a straightforward user guide and samples.  Do you have a specific problem using that tool?  Not seeing any question marks in your question...

Comment: I got this from BTrace 1.2  Using BTrace kenai.com/projects/btrace/forums/forum/topics/… – user596048 1 min ago edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) might be an option. I've never used it myself. But from the website they support annotating methods in order to instrument them. Live stats can be observed via MXBean, aka. jconsole or after the run in log files.

Comment: There are many profilers like JProbe, yourKit etc but i was really impressed by Btrace, simple and so elegant. Write simple small programs and get profiling data. No messing with the actual code either. I just liked it. One of the moderator from BTrace actually provided solution to my answer off course using Btrace. http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/forums/forum/topics/7054-Tracing-an-application-timing-for-a-single-thread